# Variance on the number of steps in an absorbing Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I've been looking for a proof for the variance on the number of steps before being absorbed in an absorbing Markov chain. The theorem is given on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Variance_on_number_of_visits) without citation.

Following the references given at the bottom of the page, in particular Kemeny & Snell's "Absorbing Markov Chains" p. 51, gave a proof but I'm struggling to follow it. I'd appreciate any help you can give in going through it, or in pointing me in the direction of another proof/resource.

Thanks.

Partial Kemeny & Snell's Proof:

\begin{align}
\{\mathbf{M}_i[t^2]\} &= \left\{ \sum\limits_{s_k \in T} p_{ik}\cdot 1 +  \sum\limits_{s_k \in T} p_{ik}\mathbf{M}_k[(t+1)^2]    \right\}\tag{1}\\
&= \left\{\sum\limits_{s_k \in T} p_{ik}(\mathbf{M}_k[t^2]+2\mathbf{M}_k[t]) +1   \right\}\tag{2}\\
&=\mathbf{Q}\{\mathbf{M}_i[t^2]\} +2\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\tau} + \mathbf{\xi}\\
\end{align}
etc

Note, here $\mathbf{M}[X]$ is the expected value of $X$, $t$ is the number of steps until absorption, $s_k$ is an arbitrary state, $p_{ik}$ are the elements in the transition matrix, $T$ is the set of all transient states (i.e. non-absorbing), $Q$ is a matrix defined in the canonical form of the transition matrix, $\mathbf{\tau}$ is a column vector of the expected number of steps, and $\xi$ is a column vector of ones.

My issue lies between lines one and two. I don't really understand why the two can be removed from the sum. In my mind, the second part of line one should expand to

\begin{align*}
p_{ik}\mathbf{M}_k[(t+1)^2]   &= p_{ik}(\mathbf{M}_k[t^2]+\mathbf{M}_k[2t]+\mathbf{M}_k[1])\\
&=p_{ik}(\mathbf{M}_k[t^2]+2\mathbf{M}_k[t]+1)
\end{align*}

and then I don't see how the two $p_{ik}$'s can result in a one outside of the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that there is a typo somewhere in (1) and you should have something like $$\sum\limits_{s_k \in A} p_{ik}\cdot 1 +  \sum\limits_{s_k \in T} p_{ik}\mathbf{M}_k[(t+1)^2]  $$ where $A$ is the set of absorbing states, i.e. $T^c$.

You will then later find yourself adding $\sum\limits_{s_k \in A} p_{ik}\cdot 1 +\sum\limits_{s_k \in T} p_{ik}\cdot 1$, i.e. $\sum\limits_{s_k \in {A \cup T}} p_{ik}\cdot 1$ which is indeed $1$.